# Conflicting types of function error

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is the first time I am working with structs and I am not sure what I am missing. The code below gives the following error on line 38:
**conflicting types for ‘encrypt’**
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

void encrypt(struct bitfield24* , struct bitfield24*, struct bitfield24*);

struct bitfield24 {
  uint32_t value : 24;
};

void main(){
    struct bitfield24 key[4];
    key[0].value = 0;
    key[1].value = 1;
    key[2].value = 2;
    key[3].value = 3;


    struct bitfield24 plain_text[2];
    plain_text[0].value = 0;
    plain_text[0].value = 1;

    struct bitfield24 cipher_text[2];
    cipher_text[0].value = 0;
    cipher_text[1].value = 0;

    struct bitfield24*  pt = plain_text;
    struct bitfield24*  ct = cipher_text;   
    struct bitfield24*  k = key;   

    encrypt(pt, ct, k);    // line 30
    printf("%x ,", ct[1].value);
    printf("%x \n", ct[0].value);
}

 /*
 * Ecnryption Method
 */
void encrypt(struct bitfield24* pt, struct bitfield24* ct, struct bitfield24* k){ //line 38

        // Encryption Algorithm
    }
```

Apart from this, here are the warnings associated with the code. The same warning is being thrown for all the 3 arguments on line 30.

**note: expected ‘struct bitfield24 *’ but argument is of type ‘struct bitfield24 *’** Please help me resolve this.

I can provide more information if need be.

Comment: Move `encript()` prototype after struct definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major issues with your code. First off all, you cannot declare a method prototype using a struct before you define the struct itself. The solution is to define the struct first:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

struct bitfield24 {
    uint32_t value : 24;
};

void encrypt(struct bitfield24* , struct bitfield24*, struct bitfield24*);
```

Secondly, your code will not compile because `main` does not return `int`. It must be defined like this:

```
int main(){
```

After this, your code compiles just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that worked. My code complies and runs fine with `void main()` too. I dont have any return statements inside my main.

Comment: @NanoNi Your code may compile with `main` declared as `void`, but it is not standards compliant, nor will it work on every system. It fails to build using `clang` on my Mac, for instance.

Comment: naturally, after correcting the main function declaration, the code needs to also have a 'return 0'' just before the final closing brace.